# Is it possible to generate random negative number range in Java?

Tags: java, random

I have seen MANY posts on here in regard to generating random numbers with a specific range in JAVA ([especially this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-integers-in-a-range-with-java/32618319#32618319)). However, I have not found one that describes how to generate a random number between a negative MAX and a negative MIN. Is this possible in Java?

For example, if I want to generate a random number that is between (-20) and (-10). Using something like the below will only result in a JAVA Exception that screams about n having to be positive:

```
int magicNumber=(random.nextInt(-20)-10);
```

Comment: How about generating a *positive* random number between 10 and 20, and then taking the negative using `-`? I think it might work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just generate a random number between 10 and 20 and then negate it.

Comment: That is more of a work around though rather than actually generating a random number. Don't you agree?

Comment: @JonathanScialpi nope

Comment: Well I don't think that's a work around the definition of a random number is that each number is equally probable to be chosen right . So by this standard that is exactly what it does. Each number in your negative range is equally probable to be chosen so I think it makes sense to use it this way.

Comment: The community has spoken @Amr . Sounds like the answer to me... just to be clear, it is not possible to use any of the random java methods to produce a negative number right?  This is due to the fact, that there must be a positive n?

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to generate a random number between 0 and 10 and then subtract 20, if that feels less like a work-around to you.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure what you want, but `ThreadLocalRandom` has a method which accepts a range, which can also have negative values:

```
ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(-20, -10 + 1)
```

There is no practical difference to just negating the result of a positive random though.